# Yolov3 not starting training

Tags: object-detection, yolo, dataset

I am trying to train custom data set that consists of currency. i followed a youtube tutorial, made the same folder structure.

I am using google colab for free gpu and darknet. everytime i run data for training it finishes within seconds without any error and the final output says "608 x 608 create 6 permanent cpu threads"
the tutorial i followed shows the training of dataset but mine is keep getting stuck at this message.

I'm using yolov3 to train my dataset, followed every step of changing things in makefile. Also the train.txt and test.txt files stays empty too. (sorry for my bad english)

Below attached screenshot of the message i get when i try to train my model.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296292/yolo-not-starting-to-train

Comment: *SOLVED* : the issue was my train.txt file was empty because it wasn’t getting any image paths, soo i changed absolute path of my images folder to relative path and it saved all the images paths in train.txt file which resulted in activation of data training(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

*SOLVED* : the issue was my train.txt file was empty because it wasn’t getting any image paths, soo i changed absolute path of my images folder to relative path and it saved all the images paths in train.txt file which resulted in activation of data training(sorry for my bad english)