# CUDA Error: out of memory (Yolov4 custom model training)

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I am trying to train a custom model on weights in the darknet and the algorithm involved is yolov4. After the model is successfully loaded, I am getting a Cuda error: out of memory as shown below.

```
896 x 896
Create 6 permanent cpu-threads
Try to set subdivisions=64 in your cfg-file.
CUDA status Error: file: D:\darknet\src\dark_cuda.c : cuda_make_array() : line: 492 : 
build time: Jan 21 2022 - 16:57:15

CUDA Error: out of memory
```

As suggested in the error I even changed my subdivision=64 in the configuration file, but still I am getting the same error. I have tried various combinations of batch and subdivisions,but I am unable to solve this issue.
I am using cuda version:10.1 and nvidia-gtx1050.

A snapshot of my configuration file:

[image]

Comment: Are you using darknet-53 as a backbone? The operations with your configuration can use quite a lot of GPU memory. I would either try to bring batch and subdivisons down to 32 or 16 and see if I still run out of memory, or try scaling down the image size to 416x416 for example.

Comment: It works after scaling down the image size to 416x416. Thank you!

Comment: You can also see an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75930463/21565398).

Answer (score 0):

if error Out of memory occurs then in .cfg-file you should increase subdivisions=16, 32 or 64

Answer (score 0):

See your resource utilization when you start training and see if the RAM causes it to exceed.
If it is so then try this solution:

[CFG-Parameters in the [net] section:](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/CFG-Parameters-in-the-%5Bnet%5D-section)

[net] section

batch - number of samples (images, letters, ...) which will be precossed in one batch

subdivisions- number of mini_batches in one batch, size mini_batch = batch/subdivisions,so GPU processes mini_batch samples at once, and the weights will be updated for batch samples (1 iteration processes batch images)

With reference from this,

I tried for min_batch=2 in google colaband that worked only  So I consider the subdivisions half of the batch like:

```
batch=64 
subdivisions=32
```

"OR"

```
batch=32
subdivisions=16
```

Or any other...